# How can we ensure that the thermal transmittance takes into account the properties of the thermal asset assigned to the material?

Tags: revit-api

## Steps to reproduce the issue

(Using Revit 2021.1.3)

1. Create materials through Revit API and assign them a thermal asset:
2. Assign material to a wall layer
3. See that thermal conductivity is filled but resistance is still 0:
   [image: thermal asset not taken into account]

---

## Explored solution

### Manual workaround

1. Manually modify any parameter like commentary
2. See that this time resistance is now not 0 which means that thermal asset is now taken into account
   [image: thermal asset taken into account]

### Things which did not work

1. Modify commentary through Revit API in a separate transaction

## Current work in progress source code

Current work in progress source code can be found [in pyRevitMEP repo](https://github.com/CyrilWaechter/pyRevitMEP/blob/566e76889df9287f19f516c77b00b5114c2f843d/pyRevitMEP.tab/Data.panel/MaterialsDB.pulldown/CreateAllMaterials.pushbutton/script.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an example in [Revit API documentation](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/2528df8e-9c01-10be-f6be-f0ebbd9ff4bc.htm). Apparently setting thermal property set through [`ThermalAssetId` property](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/76db3e11-fdaa-14f1-58c6-6f66ed70e0bd.htm) is not the way to go. We need to use [`SetMaterialAspectByPropertySet` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/73438593-0643-93d6-5c58-1fb39e2efd47.htm) instead.

```py
revit_material = doc.GetElement(Material.Create(doc, layer_name))
thermal_asset = ThermalAsset(layer_name, ThermalMaterialType.Solid)
thermal_asset.ThermalConductivity = UnitUtils.ConvertToInternalUnits(
                    thermal_conductivity,
                    DisplayUnitType.DUT_WATTS_PER_METER_KELVIN,
                )
thermal_property_set = PropertySetElement.Create(doc, thermal_asset)

material.SetMaterialAspectByPropertySet(MaterialAspect.Thermal, thermal_property_set.Id)
```